# How to compute the sum of each element in N arrays, and store it in another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

**Problem**

Currently, I have two arrays (but the overall amount is dynamic, not necessarily always 2) and I need a way to sum each index of each array (as in, index 0 of array 1 + index 0 of array 2, index 1 of array 1 + index 1 of array 2 and so on..) and then store the collection of sums computed into its own array.

**What the Arrays Look Like**

```
[ 0.9716351, 1.116535, 1.316175 ] -- Array 1
[ 0.937825,  1.09963, 1.358035 ] -- Array 2
```

**What I'm Trying to Do**

I'm trying to add the indexes of Array 1 and 2 together, and store the sum of each index into a new "sum" array. As in:

```
sum = [0.9716351 + 0.937825, 1.116535+1.09963, 1.316175+1.358035] and so on.
```

I've tried mapping over the array's and summing them but it's not summing the correct indexes and storing them in a new array entirely.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested `forEach`, so that it work for dynamic number of arrays.

```js
const data = [
  [0.9716351, 1.116535, 1.316175],
  [0.937825, 1.09963, 1.358035],
];

const res = [];

data.forEach((arr) => {
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    res[index] = (res[index] ?? 0) + item;
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This method will work even for any number of arrays that have any length ( They can be different)!

```js
let arrays = [
  [0.9716351, 1.116535, 1.316175],
  [0.937825, 1.09963, 1.358035]
]
let sum = [];
let arrLengths = [];

for (array of arrays) {
  arrLengths.push(array.length)
}
let gLength = Math.max(...arrLengths)

for (let i = 0; i < gLength; i++) {
  let thisSum = 0
  for (let p = 0; p < arrays.length; p++) {
    thisSum += arrays[p][i] || 0;
  }
  sum[i] = thisSum
}
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: This doesn't scale to N arrays.